# Iterating over custom list and checking the value of attribute at each index

Tags: java

I have a POJO:

```
public class BrokerInvoiceLineItem {
    private Date dealDate;
    private String brokerRefId;
    private String receiverName;
    private double notional;
    private double fixedRate;
    private Date maturityDate;
    private double amount;

}
```

A list of these POJOs is fetched by a method as shown below:

```
 List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> finalBrokerInvoiceLineItemList = brokerInvoice.getLineItems();
```

I need an exception to be thrown if any field in any POJO stored in the list is null.

How should I iterate over finalBrokerInvoiceLineItemList and for every item check the value of the above fields and throw an exception if any of them is null.

Comment: @gfgfhjfgjgng, please review my edit, roll back if needed.

Answer (score -1):

The `for-each` construct is used for iterating over collections in java.

```
for(BrokerInvoiceLineItem item : brokerInvoice.getLineItems()) {
    if(item.getDealDate() == null)
        throw Exception();
}
```

The argument on the left is the variable that will be passed into the loop target (which can be a block or a statement), and the argument on the right identifies the collection to be iterated. In this case you need to iterate over the collection checking if each item's date is null, which is achieved with a simple `if` statement, throwing an exception if `null` is found.

Comment: Please read [answer] -- your answer is 'code only' -- SO much prefers some words around the code to explain how it help the OP solve their problem

Comment: @EngineerDollery Edited.

Comment: Because I'm bored, I decided to show you what I meant. Your solution, whilst better than beofre, was actually just a translation of the code to English -- which isn't that helpful given that the code is a less ambiguous and easier to read version of the same thing. I've removed my downvote anyway.